# Cannot change selection of jquery mobile radio button

Tags: jquery, mobile, radio-button

I keep getting the error "Object doesn't support property or method 'checkboxradio'". I am using the latest jquery mobile 1.4.3, Visual Studio 2013 and Internet Explorer 11. My main objective is to put it into a c# code behind to change the radio button selection based on information retrieved from database.

I have also tried the following 
$('input[id*=radio-choice-h-Corporate').attr('checked',true).checkboxradio('refresh');
$('#radio-choice-h-Corporate').prop('checked',false).checkboxradio('refresh');

none of this work

```html
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Customer Type:</legend>
    <input name="radioCustomerType" id="radio-choice-h-Personal" value="1"  type="radio">
    <label for="radio-choice-h-Personal">Personal</label>
    <input name="radioCustomerType" id="radio-choice-h-Corporate" value="2" type="radio">
    <label for="radio-choice-h-Corporate">Corporate</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#radio-choice-h-Corporate').attr("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to trigger refresh on all input radio elements:

```
$('#radio-choice-h-Corporate').attr("checked", false);
$("input[type='radio']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```